# Rules of finding maxima and minima of a function

Tags: calculus

In my math-book one of the rules of finding maximum and minimum value is:

- If at x = a, the first and second derivative of a function is $0$ and third derivative is **not** $0$ then the function at that point does not have a maximum or minimum value.

I can't  understand why this is true.

Comment: Think at $\,y=x^3\,$ around $\,x=0\,$ for example.

Comment: can you provide some details?

Comment: $y = x^3$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$ so it has no extrema. At $x=0$ `the first and second derivative ... is 0 and third derivative is not 0` so this is an example of function with the given properties.